dividing the determinant of a matrix by the expected value of the determinant of the same matrix over a uniform distribution
Let $A, B$ be square $n \times n$ matrices as follows:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\
  x_{n+1}&x_{n+2}&\cdots&x_{2n}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  x_{n^2-n+1}&x_{n^2-n+2}&\cdots&x_{n^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
  X_1&X_2&\cdots&X_n\\
  X_{n+1}&X_{n+2}&\cdots&X_{2n}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  X_{n^2-n+1}&X_{n^2-n+2}&\cdots&X_{n^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $X_i$s are uniform random variables such that
$$
X_i \sim U(0,x_i).
$$
I need to compute the following expression
$$
\dfrac{E[\det(B)]}{\det(A)}.
$$
My Solution
Since $X_i \sim U(0,x_i)$, then the expected value of $X_i$ is $\dfrac{x_i}{2}$, therefore the expression
$$
\dfrac{E[\det(B)]}{\det(A)}
$$
is going to be
$$
\dfrac{1}{2^n}
$$
Although I suspect my guess $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ is true, I believe the reasoning is wrong because The expected value of the determinant of a matrix is not equal to the determinant of the expected value of that matrix. I would like to know what is the solution to
$$
\dfrac{E[\det(B)]}{\det(A)}
$$
Many thanks for considering my request.

$X_i$'s are independent random variables, so the expectation of their product is there product of expectations, hence your solution is ok

@user8268 Yes every $X_i$ is an independent random variable. Therefore expanding the determinant of $B$ will be a set of plus, minus, and product of random variables. Right?

Better to write $X_{ij}=x_{ij}U_{ij}$ with $U_{ij}$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and independent. Therefore
$$E(\det B)=E(\sum_{\sigma}\epsilon(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^nU_{i,\sigma(i)}x_{i,\sigma(i)})$$$$=\sum_{\sigma}\epsilon(\sigma)E(\prod_{i=1}^nU_{i,\sigma(i)})\prod_{i=1}^nx_{i,\sigma(i)}$$$$=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{\sigma}\epsilon(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^nx_{i,\sigma(i)}=\frac{1}{2^n}\det A.$$

what are $\sigma$ and $\epsilon$?

The index $ \sigma$ describes the whole set of of the $n!$ permutations of ${1,2,\ldots,n}$ and $\epsilon(\sigma)=\pm 1$ is the signature of $\sigma.$ There are many equivalent definitions of this object. Here is one: $$\epsilon(\sigma)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}.$$
